# Decomposition of Galois group into direct product using the main theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I have a question concerning the main theorem of Galois theory: If $K$ is a field with finite Galois extensions $M,Z$, so that $K\subset M\subset Z$, the theorem says that $$Gal(Z/K)/Gal(Z/M)\cong Gal(M/K). \text{ }(1)$$

So, can one also say that $$Gal(Z/K)\cong Gal(Z/M)\times Gal(M/K)?$$

Intuitively, I think this could be true because one constructs the elements in $Gal(Z/K)$ by taking elements in $Gal(M/K)$ and extending them to automorphisms over $Z$. So I think of a homomorphism like $$Gal(Z/M)\times Gal(M/K)\rightarrow Gal(Z/K),\text{ } (\sigma,\rho) \mapsto \psi,$$ where $$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}\sigma(x) &: x\in Z\setminus M\\ \rho(x) &: x\in M.\end{cases}$$

It is injective, since $\psi = id$ means that $\sigma = id|_{Z\setminus M}$ (it is already given that $\sigma|_M = id|_M$) and $\rho = id_M$, so $(\sigma,\rho) = id$.

And because of (1), I think it should also be surjective.

Comment: No, this is not true. It could be a semidirect product or a more general group extension.

Comment: Are the fields finite? I'm a bit suspicious, because then all the Galois groups would be cyclic, and you should be able to answer the question easily enough. The claim still would not be true. For example, it is possible that the big Galois group is $\simeq C_4$ and the two smaller ones both $\simeq C_2$. Anyway, I think you may have mistagged.